# Problem with jQuery JSONP twitter search request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, jsonp

I'm having some difficulties to correctly retrieve Twitter data using jsonp search.json.

**When I fetch the data only once, it works perfectly with this piece of code :**

```
function getTweets(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonpCallback: 'tw_callback',
       data: 'q=<?php echo urlencode($twitter_search); ?>+-RT&rpp=100'
    });
}

function tw_callback(jsonp){
    for( key in jsonp['results'] ) {    
        var tweet = jsonp['results'][key]['text'] ;
        var from = jsonp['results'][key]['from_user'];
        var avatar = jsonp['results'][key]['profile_image_url'];

        tw_container.push([tweet,from,avatar]);
    }
}
```

**But when I try then to refresh this data every xx seconds, using setInterval:**

```
setInterval(function () { getTweets(); }, 1000*interval_tourniquet);
```

It unfortunately doesn't work. I'm having this error:

> NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An
>   attempt was made to reference a Node
>   in a context where it does not exist.

basically, I got this every time I try to call my getTweets() function inside another function... :(

**Other solution I tried :**

```
function getTweets(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: 'callback=tw_callback&q=<?php echo urlencode($twitter_search); ?>+-RT&rpp=100'
    });
}
```

This way it works perfectly with my own jsonp api on another server, but Twitter returns me my callback twice:

> tw_callback(tw_callback({results...

And the jsonp string is not interpreted..

Any clue on this, any hint?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: I just tested in Chrome with no problem. The only change I made was to replace the contents of `tw_callback` with `console.log(jsonp)`. What browser are you using and do you have the same problem in multiple browsers? This should have not impact but you can shorten `setInterval` to `setInterval(getTweets, 1000*interval_tourniquet);`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on Chrome or Safari for me.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite your function with the following, more simple, way.

```
function getTweets(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=<?php echo urlencode($twitter_search); ?>&rpp=100&callback=?',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(){ 

            for( key in jsonp['results'] ) {    
                var tweet = jsonp['results'][key]['text'] ;
                var from = jsonp['results'][key]['from_user'];
                var avatar = jsonp['results'][key]['profile_image_url'];

                tw_container.push([tweet,from,avatar]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the `&callback=?` do?

Comment: It is a placeholder for jQuery to supply a function name, which will receive the response. For example jQuery will generate a function callback123 and argument will look like &callback=callback123 and JSONP response will look like callback123({ your: response, data: ...}). Also, as request type is set to JSONP, it will not be requested with XMLHttpRequest, but with simple script tag which src is matching your URL.